# Solr4.0 with Tomcat 7 installation error

Tags: tomcat, solr

After trying to install Solr4.0 alpha on tomcat, I can never get to the admin gui, as I get the following error message:

```
This interface requires that you activate the admin request handlers, add the following configuration to your solrconfig.xml:
<!-- Admin Handlers - This will register all the standard admin RequestHandlers. -->
<requestHandler name="/admin/" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
```

and even after adding them to the solrconfig.xml (they actually already existed), the admin gui will still not load. I have seen some bugs reported on apache, but none of them fix the problem. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a rather vague error given by the solr admin console saying that ... something ... is wrong with the Solr configuration.  Your best bet is to go to your tomcat logs (maybe catalina file) and have a look.  This will probably give you some insight into what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error. When reviewing the catalina log i noticed:

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "MA147LL/A"

Apparently in solr4 alpha this error has been reported when your unique key field is defined as a "long" type field.  I changed this field to a string and it resolved my error.  Might not be the same as yours though but worth a shot.